# The Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

What's the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s}{(s-5)^4}$?  I'm thinking of adding zero to the top and dividing out to get rid of the top s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Do the partial fraction expansion as:

$$\dfrac{s}{(s-5)^4} = \dfrac{5}{(s -5)^4} + \dfrac{1}{(s -5 )^3}$$

Now, use a [*Table of Laplace Transforms*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) or use the ILT definition to find the inverse.

**Spoiler**

> $\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left(\dfrac{5}{(s -5)^4} + \dfrac{1}{(s -5 )^3}\right) = \dfrac{6}{5}t^3~e^{5t} + \dfrac{1}{2}t^2~e^{5 t} = \dfrac{1}{6}~t^2~e^{5t}~\left(5t + 3\right)$

Comment: You've been busy in the last twelve + hours! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Was tired from reviews and working on presentation, so answered a few! Hope you had a great TG!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\gamma > 5$:

> \begin{align}
> \int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}
> {s\expo{st} \over \pars{s - 5}^{4}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
> &=
> {1 \over \pars{4 - 1}!}\lim_{s \to 5}\partiald[3]{}{s}
> \bracks{{\pars{s - 5}^{4}s\expo{st} \over \pars{s - 5}^{4}}}
> =
> {1 \over 6}\lim_{s \to 5}\partiald[3]{\pars{s\expo{st}}}{s}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over 6}\lim_{s \to 5}\pars{\expo{st}t^{3}s + 3\expo{st}t^{2}}
> =
> {1 \over 6}\pars{5t^{3}\expo{5t} + 3t^{2}\expo{5t}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}
{s\expo{st} \over \pars{s - 5}^{4}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
=
{1 \over 6}\pars{5t + 3}t^{2}\expo{5t}}
$$